# Find angle between two vectors using inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products

$u=(0,-5), v=(4,3)$ and $\langle u,v \rangle=2u_1v_1+u_2v_2$ The problem says to find the angle $\theta$ between the vectors and round your answer to the two decimal places. I've been trying to do this, but my answer is a bit off. The answer should be $2.06$ radians. 
[This is what I've been trying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q11r.png) 
I've gotten $2.18$ radians. I'm not sure about where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You should have $\sqrt{2(4)^2 + (3)^2}$ in the denominator instead of $\sqrt{2(3)^2 + (3)^2}$; maybe that's your mistake

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation + please type your work instead of a link

Comment: @BenGrossmann Why is there a $2$?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Because of how the inner product is defined (at the top of the question)

Answer (score 1):

Salaam!
Let $u=(u_1,u_2)$ and $v=(v_1,v_2)$ be vectors, we have the dot product defined as follows: $$<u,v> = 2u_1 v_1 + u_2  v_2$$.
Also, $$<u,v>= \mid u \mid \mid v \mid cos \theta$$ where:
$$\mid u \mid =\sqrt {(u_1^2+u_2^2)}$$
$$ \mid v \mid =\sqrt{ (2v_1^2+v_2^2)}$$
and $\theta$ is the angle between vectors $u$ and $v$.  Thus, in your example, we have $$u=(0,-5), v=(4,3)$$
Thus,
$$<u,v>=(0 \times 4)+(-5 \times  3)=-15$$
$$\mid u \mid = \sqrt{ 0^2 + (-5)^2} =5$$
$$\mid v \mid = \sqrt{ 2\times 4^2 + 3^2} =\sqrt{41}$$
 $$\theta = cos^{-1}(\frac{{-15}}{5 \times \sqrt{41}}) \approx 2.06$$
I hope this helps! please, feel free to ask more questions if you still have any.